# Why rehashing will make it more secure?

Tags: security, hash

Reading a book that said: Repeatedly rehashing to obtain more computationally intensive byte sequence. If you rehashing 100 times, a dictionary attack that might otherwise take 1 month would take 8 years. Why? I don't understand. Anyone can explain?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a hashing function like this:

```
password_hash = MD5(password)
```

Given a hash, say 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99, your preferred technique will be to generate hashes of all the words in a dictionary using the above function and then compare the password_hash to the one you want to reverse.

Now suppose you change your hashing function to

```
   password_hash = password
   for i = 1 to 100
     password_hash = MD5(password_hash)
   next
```

As an attacker, this time you'll have to hash each word in your dictionary 100 times to compare it with the given hash you want to brute force. Hence it takes much longer for an attacker to brute force a given hash if you've hashed your password multiple times.

It is for this very purpose, fast hashing algorithms like MD5 and SHA family aren't very suitable for hashing passwords. You can read http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ to get insight of how a slow algorithm like bcrypt is more suited for password hashing.